# How to check that popup notification is NOT displayed. Espresso

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have popup notification. My first test checks if that notification is displayed and it passes succesfully. I use next method for this test:

```
fun viewInNotificationPopupIsDisplayed(viewMatcher: Matcher<View>) {
    onView(viewMatcher)
        .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
        .check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

I have a problem with second test case where i have to check that my popup notification has already gone (means it's not displayed anymore).
So i'm trying to use next method:

```
    fun viewInNotificationPopupIsNotDisplayed(viewMatcher: Matcher<View>) {
        Espresso.onView(viewMatcher)
            .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
            .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
          //.check(ViewAssertions.doesNotExist())  // doesn't work as well
    }
```

I get next exception:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: 
Matcher 'with decor view of type PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer' 
did not match any of the following roots: 
[Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@bb8371e,
 window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@bb8371e, has-window-focus=true,
```

Please, can anybody help with this?

Comment: Have you found the answer? I have the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that such simple check is impossible with espresso if you have a `PopupWindow` because of the way the `NoMatchingRootException` is thrown

You may just catch the exception and complete the test but that's not a good option since throwing and catching `NoMatchingRootException` consumes a lot of time in a comparison with the default test case. Seems that Espresso is waiting for the Root for a while

For this case is suggest just to give up with espresso here and use `UiAutomator` for this assertion

```
val device: UiDevice
   get() = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

fun assertPopupIsNotDisplayed() {
    device.waitForIdle()
    assertFalse(device.hasObject(By.text(yourText))))
}

fun assertPopupIsDisplayed() {
    device.waitForIdle()
    assertTrue(device.hasObject(By.text(yourText))))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! It's the only way I managed to get the negative condition to work.